# UISegmentedControl crash app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

It is code to create `UISegmentedControl` then add it in `leftBarButtonItem`. it is in viewDidLoad

```
UISegmentedControl *prevNextSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] init];

[prevNextSegment setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[prevNextSegment setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[prevNextSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(prevNextSegmentAction:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
prevNextSegment.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 95,35);
prevNextSegment.momentary = YES;
self.prevNextSeg_ = prevNextSegment;
[prevNextSegment release], prevNextSegment = nil;



UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithCustomView:self.prevNextSeg_ ];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
[segmentBarItem release];
```

Another method accessing the `UISegmentedControl` for disable the segment, use the following code

```
[self.prevNextSeg_ setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

This line of code crash the app. And get the exception like this

```
2014-08-12 09:31:08.386 FinApp[29694:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',   
reason: '*** -   [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

I dont know how to solve this. I search google, but didnt get suitable solution for this problem.

Comment: Remove all `release` and `nil` statement code, it will solve your issue.

Comment: 1) How did you define your `prevNextSeg_` property? 2) Why aren't you using the `initWithItems:` method to create the segmented control? 3) Why aren't you using ARC?

Comment: Answer for ur questions 1) '@property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *prevNextSeg_;' 2) First i tried with 'initWithItems' same result only i got 3) It is the old app, not enable ARC

Comment: Is it possible that at the time of the crash, `self.prevNextSeg_` is pointing to an uninitialized (no items) segmented control?

Comment: At the time of crash it is initialized but no items. I dont know what is happening.

Comment: Finally i solve this issue. I didnt refer the up.png and down.png images with xcode. So it not create the segment.

Answer (score 1):

insert some items to show up on segment control

**Reason for crash:**

You dont have any items on segment control. its empty. first you must insert some items on it. then try to access it. other wise the crash will happen.

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:@[@"Up",@"Down"]];



if ([segmentControl numberOfSegments]>1) {

    [segmentControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];

}
```

If you want to insert the items later , then use this method. Refer the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-DontLinkElementID_5)

```
– insertSegmentWithImage:atIndex:animated:
– insertSegmentWithTitle:atIndex:animated:
```

Comment: It is working good. But i need to show the image instead of text in segment.

Comment: Finally i solve this issue. I didnt refer the up.png and down.png images with xcode. So it not create the segment. Thanks